# Wordpress - wp_list_pages - Is there a limit?

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

wp_list_pages and wp_dropdown_pages doesn't output anything if my post type has more than 100 pages. I tried it on post types and taxonomies that have a smaller number of pages and it works, but I have 3 custom post types with large number of entries in them. Does anyone know why it wont work when theres more than 100 pages to display and what I can do to fix that?

EDIT: I just realised its not a matter of there being too many posts, the problem must be something else. I can't figure out what the problem could be, the way I registered the working and broken post types are identical. I can't see any pattern here. Can anyone suggest a way of debugging this problem? To get an idea of what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you have debug enabled?

Comment: Ah wait sorry, I just realised that one of the post types thats not displaying only has 10 entries so its not a matter of there being too many posts in the table. Yeah I have debug enabled, no warnings or errors are reported. I cant figure out why this is just not working for these post types. I'll post the code I used to register the post types.

Comment: If you have found the solution please answer your own question or close it. "Something else" is not a good information.

Comment: It could be the memory issue on your Server? Increasing the memory limit might resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was that the custom post types have to be set to hierarchical (when registering them, I don't mean setting the wp_list_pages argument to hierarchical). So the ones that weren't working, I had to set them to hierarchical now they work.